# Are Bayesian models just frequentist models with one more layer?

Tags: bayesian, frequentist

We all know the formula for Bayesian inference:

$$P(\theta|\mathbf{x}) = \frac{P(\theta|\gamma)P(\mathbf{x}|\theta)}{P(\mathbf{x})}$$

In this approach, we replace a fixed $\theta$ with a latent, random effect $\theta \sim P(\theta|\gamma)$ with $\gamma$ being what are called "hyperparameters". Now, in the context of inferring $\theta$, this approach differs markedly from the frequentist approach, where our only source of randomness comes from the data generated by the true model.

However, what if we were to try to estimate $\gamma$? -- it seems that we've simply "plugged in" an estimate for $\gamma$ and went from there; yet, we are assuming $\gamma$ is fixed.

How is this not just like the frequentist paradigm? In other words, have we used Bayes theorem to simply move the frequentist aspect up one level, where we care less about the accuracy or actual value of the hyperparameter?

Comment: Plugging fixed values in Bayes theorem does not make the approach Bayesian, ironically. The Bayesian approach manipulates random variables that "carry" information about uncertainty via distribution, not a fixed value.

Comment: @VladislavsDovgalecs thanks...I was trying to point out that if we were interested in inferring the hyperparameter of a Bayesian model from the data, then we'd be in the same boat as the frequentists...the hyperparameter is fixed in the above model.

Comment: I am not so sure. In OP, you state that \theta is inferred, not the hyperparameters. The hyperparameters express the belief or lack of thereof on the model parameters being inferred. If you want to infer the hyperparameters, you must add more structure (and make sure the data has it) to the model. In other words, one must understand very well the model and the process it approximates. If the hyperparameter is fixed, there is nothing to infer; it will come back as a pointmass.

Comment: @VladislavsDovgalecs I guess my point is that the model assumes a fixed hyperparameter (and actually provides it value), which is similar in spirit to a frequentist who assumes there is one fixed value for $\theta$, its just that the fixed value parameter is "up" one level.

Comment: Are you familiar with the "8 schools" example? Can you model and infer the quantities the hierarchical bayesian model does using a frequentist approach? There is this top-level hyper parameter set that allows the information to flow between the groups and allows better parameter estimates. And does all the weighting automatically.

Comment: @VladislavsDovgalecs yes I am -- I doubt you could directly use any frequentist procedure on a Bayesian model.My contention is more philosophical -- that Bayesians don't allow all parameters to be random, just the ones they care about. In this sense, they act like frequentists using mixed effects models.

Comment: I think I see your point better. Indeed, in a Bayesian model some hyperparameters must be fixed. And that makes sense since yesterday's posterior is today prior. A fixed hyperparameter defines the shape of a prior distribution. Looks fine with me.